# How to use or integrate github copilot in monaco-editor

Tags: monaco-editor, github-copilot

Please someone explain me how to integrate github copliot and Monaco-Editor

Someone please explain how to solve this and share code snippets.

Comment: I am looking for something similar. Did you get any solutions?